# Java RPS game with Rounds

Tags: java

I am very new to Java, I have a very basic RPS game done and I need to add rounds to it, I want to have 5 rounds, and then at the end decide who is the winner, the computer, or the player. I tried a for loop with incrementation, but I had no success.

```
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Scanner;

class Program
{
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        
        int R = 1; 
        int P = 2; 
        int S = 3; 

        
        int u; 
        int c; 
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random myRand = new Random(); 
        
        
        System.out.println("1. Rock");
        System.out.println("2. Paper");
        System.out.println("3. Scissors");
        
        u = myScan.nextInt(); 
        
        c = myRand.nextInt(3); 
        
        
        System.out.println("c = " + c + " u = " + u);
        
        if ( u==c )
        {
            System.out.println("Tie Game!");
        }
        else if ( (u==R && c==S) || (u==S && c==P) || (u==P && c== R) )
        {
            System.out.println("User Wins!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Computer WIns!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? What is your desired result, and what is the current result you are getting?

Comment: You tried a for-loop? You had some kind of problem with it? Details?

Comment: I tried making a rounds counter, using a for loop, incrementing it by 1 until it is equal to 5, and then once it is to then end the game. currently it is only 1 round and then it decides the winner,  my desired result is for the game to go for 5 rounds and at the end compare the two scores, whichever being the biggest then printing that that computer/user has won.

Comment: I don't see any of that loop code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a for-loop and keep track of score. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int R = 1;
    int P = 2;
    int S = 3;

    int u;
    int c;

    int uWins = 0;
    int cWins = 0;

    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random myRand = new Random();

    for (int rounds = 0; rounds < 5; rounds++) {
        System.out.println("1. Rock");
        System.out.println("2. Paper");
        System.out.println("3. Scissors");

        u = myScan.nextInt() - 1;

        c = myRand.nextInt(3);

        System.out.println("c = " + c + " u = " + u);

        if ((u == R && c == S) || (u == S && c == P) || (u == P && c == R)) {
            uWins++;
        } else {
            cWins++;
        }
    }

    if (uWins == cWins) {
        System.out.println("Tie Game!");
    } else if ((uWins == R && cWins == S) || (uWins == S && cWins == P) || (uWins == P && cWins == R)) {
        System.out.println("User Wins!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Computer WIns!");
    }

}
```

I changed `u = myScan.nextInt()` to `u = myScan.nextInt() - 1` to account for the fact that `Rand.nextInt(3)` returns either 0, 1, or 2.